# Injectivity or projectivity criterion in modules and model categories

Tags: category-theory, modules, projective-module, injective-module, model-categories

Here in Hovey's book on Model Categories in as opposed to [errata](https://books.google.cz/books?id=cyn0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=errata+hovey+model+%22lemma+2.2.8%22&source=bl&ots=I5Is27oIUC&sig=ACfU3U1ucpjK4ZFYpEcuI0c0Fre7zPaCmg&hl=cs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEm9KOkI3tAhUxy4UKHY5mBBcQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=errata%20hovey%20model%20%22lemma%202.2.8%22&f=false) there is already **injective** in the lemma 2.2.8.
The errata says **injective** and not **projective**.
Also I wonder what is $A$ in $A\to Q$ there.

[image]

Comment: In lemma 2.2.8, $A$ is the base ring $Q$. Looks like a *lapsus calami*. Ift often happens that rings are denoted $A$, $B, \dots$.

Comment: *A should be the base ring R (as I believe you said) not Q. This is known as Baer's criterion, and it's a standard criterion for checking injectivity of a module.

Comment: @Aragogh Right, but the errata says **injective** where it already **is** injective used.

Comment: Error in the errata? As stated it’s correct, with A changed to R